# Sequelize -> Group By field and pick max of another field

Tags: sql, node.js, database, group-by, sequelize.js

In my schema, an `Item` can have multiple `Orders`. Each `Order` has a price. I'm trying to get all the orders placed by a given user, group this by the `itemId` (only one order per item) and ensure that this item is the one with the highest price.

So for example, if the `Order` table looks like this:

```
  ID | ItemID | UserID | Price |  
 ----|--------|--------|-------|-- 
   1 |      1 |      1 |   200 |  
   2 |      1 |      1 |   300 |  
   3 |      2 |      2 |   100 |  
   4 |      2 |      1 |   300 |
```

If `userId` is 1, I  want to return:

2 1 1 300 (since this order for item with ID 1 has the highest price)

and

4 2 1 300

Using the below code I'm able to fetch all the orders for a given user, but I'm not sure how to apply the above conditions:

```
 Orders.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: id
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Items
          include: [{ model: DefaultItem, include: [Default] }]
        }
      ]
    })
      .then(orders => res.json(orders))
```

Comment: Getting a list of the highest price per item is straightforward - `Orders.findAll({
     where : {userId: id},
     attributes: ['itemID',
            [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('price')),'max_price']
        ],
        group : ['product_id']                    
    })`  but getting order ID is more complicated.  To do so would involve joining the above as a sub-query back to the Orders model -  easy in raw SQL, not too easy in Sequelize.

Comment: @KenOn10 I need to take all the fields from `Orders`, not just itemId and max_price...I get the following error: `{ Error: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'orders.items.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Sorry about the error - I was testing with a different table and forgot to translate back to your names.  Try: `Orders.findAll({ where : {userId: id}, attributes: ['itemID', [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('price')),'max_price'] ], group : ['itemID'] })`

Comment: What result do you expect if the highest price is on multiple orders (e.g. if ID=1 also had price=300)?

Comment: @KenOn10 that's not possible, only one item can have the highest price...can you post an answer so I can accept